# access method "btree" does not exist in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I can not create a table using the `uuid_generate_v4()` in Postgres as I keep getting this error:

> access method "btree" does not exist

What should I do? and how is that  `uuid_generate_v4()`
 related to btree?

This is the query I m running

```
create table events (
  id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4() not null,
  name text not null
);
```

Comment: Please include the db version and all the relevant information (what extensions you have installed, their version if need be etc.).

Comment: Did you install the extension `"uuid-ossp"`?

Comment: its postgre 9.4. and yes i have `installed uuid-ossp`

Comment: does `gen_random_uuid()` function from `pg_crypto` work for you?..

Comment: Does it work if you create the table without the default value?

Comment: yes it does work without a default value. thanks.  I have just removed it and everything worked fine

Comment: Works fine for me with 9.4.5. What is your **exact** Postgres version? [edit] your question and add the output of `select version()`. Was the database upgraded from an earlier version? If yes, you might need to run `alter extension "uuid-ossp" update`

Comment: I am using postfress `PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently removing the `Default` keyword helped in getting rid of that error. I still don't a clear idea why was that happening though, therefore, any further explanation would be helpful.